# Form - Create new record in *different* table based on current form data

Tags: ms-access

I'm building a risk and issues tracker and have become stuck after some good initial progress. I'll explain my setup now.

Tables

- A table containing all open projects
- A table containing all open
  risks and issues

Relationships

- A one-to-many relationship between with project ID (Primary Key in the project table) to the risks and issues table

Queries

- A query that will filter results from the **projects** table that have been selected in a combo box

Forms

- One form containing a combobox that allows the user to select a project. There is also a text box, which will be populated based on the selected project. The text box is populated using DLookUp on the above query, and I have chosen a field to be populated from that. This all works fine.

---

I am able to select a project and see a little information about it using the above set up. The next step for me is to be able to add a risk or an issue.

What I would like to happen is to have a create Risk / Issue button, which will pull across the Project ID (primary key) from the selected project, and add a new record in the **risks and issues* table. I will also need to add in additional information about the risk, dates, owner etc.

Also, by having the project primary key tied to each risk, I should be able to pull in any additional info about the project that I require.

---

I can write more if required - I'm not really sure which information is needed. Also, the form 'sits on' my **projects** table which could well have been the wrong way of doing things, however I still don't know how to bring in the data from two different tables.

I appreciate any effort and patience put towards this.

Comment: So, you want to add an entry to the risks and issues table using a combobox to select a Project by and use that `ProjectID` in your new record?

Comment: Exactly - is there anything else I should add?

Comment: Do you have a form built already that you're trying to utilize? Or are you comfortable with creating a new form, or how do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question it sounds like your trying to update your risks and issues table with a single form that is bound to your projects table. If you're adding a record to risk issue table with a bound form it needs to be bound to that table.
My best answer would be to start fresh with a new form created by the wizard.

1. Make sure you have all the fields you want in your form in the risks and issues table.
2. Create a form based on this table using the wizard.
3. Change the Project ID control to a combobox by right clicking and selecting change to, combobox.
4. Set the row source to take project id and project from the project table and then make sure project id is the bound field and project is  the displayed field(by adjusting column widths and bound column properties).

After doing this you should have a form that updates your risk and issues table while selecting the project from your project table. If this is not what you were asking or you wanted to do it a different way let me know I'll see if I can help.